# Can this async code complete out of order?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have the following C# code in an AspNet WebApi controller:

```
private static async Task<string> SaveDocumentAsync(HttpContent content) {
    var path = "something";
    using (var file = File.OpenWrite(path)) {
        await content.CopyToAsync(file);
    }
    return path;
}

public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put() {
    var path = await SaveDocumentAsync(Request.Content);
    await SaveDbRecordAsync(path); // writes something to the database using System.Data and awaiting Async methods
    return OK();
}
```

I am sometimes seeing the database record visible before the document has finished being written. Is this a possible execution sequence? (It is also possible my file system isn't giving me the semantics I want).

To clarify how I'm observing this. It is an application that is reading the path out of the database and then trying to read the file and finding it isn't there. The file does appear shortly afterwards.
This doesn't happen every time, normally the file comes first. Maybe 1 in 1000 it happens the wrong way.

**This turned out to be down to file system semantics. I thought I'd excluded my replicated file system, but I'd done it wrong. The code is behaving as expected.**

Comment: `I am sometimes seeing the database record visible before the document has finished being written.` - Probably solution explorer just updates later than your db does. File is there, but it appears with delay since it's not indexed via VS instantly

Comment: I have seen in applications of mine that the IO Api is unreliable in terms of the write operations being complete. Very much possible that the call returns but saving in the File drive is not complete yet.

Comment: +1 to @gpanagopoulos's comment. To be specific, I've seen `File.Move()` return before the operation completed on docker-alpine. Switching the base image from alpine to debian fixed the problem. This was on .NET Core 2.2.

Comment: Let's assume there are no bugs in the underlying .net libraries. They execute in order. Are you sure the request is not fired twice while you are debugging it for example? Sometimes requests are fired again with some retry mechanism in the client app.

Comment: @Neistow Visual Studio isn't involved in this. I've updated the question to clarify.

Comment: @Laurence Are you using a file-system synchronisation service? If your application is load-balanced and you're accessing the path referring to the current pod/machine and you are using a service that synchronises the file system, then you can indeed run into missing files, because synchronisation could take a couple of ms. If that is the case, you might want to consider some sort of dedicated blob-storage.

Comment: @Silvermind I was doing something like that originally, but I thought I'd eliminated it before asking the question. I'm using an SMB share. It is possible this is an artefact of client caching, but it is an odd one if so, because SMB has both positive and negative cache. The consumer shouldn't be requesting the file before it is written, so the negative cache on that machine should never get populated.

Comment: @gpanagopoulos. I'm using .Net Framework on Windows. While I can't rule out bugs, it's more likely something I'm doing.

Comment: *"An application is reading the path out of the database, and then trying to read the file, and finds it isn't there."* <= this indicates that the file was not written at all, not that it was written out of order. Is it possible that some antivirus program deletes files that look like viruses?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias. The file turns up shortly afterwards.

Comment: Could you try disposing the `HttpContent` after you are done with it, to see if it makes any difference?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I'll try that. Will take some time as this is currently a live only problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're `await`ing `SaveDocumentAsync` function before you call `SaveDbRecordAsync`, it executes **after** `SaveDocumentAsync` completes.

If you were to fire the tasks in parallel then `await` them:

```cs
var saveTask = SaveDocumentAsync(Request.Content);
var dbTask = SaveDbRecordAsync("a/path.ext");

await saveTask;
await dbTask;
```

then you wouldn't be able to guarantee the completion order.

@Neiston touches a good point: it might be that the app you're using to view the results might be updating with a delay and causing you to think the order is switched.

Comment: Where has `path` come from here?

Comment: It's a typo from copy-paste.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense as an example now because `SaveDbRecordAsync` is dependant on the result of `SaveDocumentAsync`.

Comment: True. I should have used a different example. The point is there shouldn't be an out-of-order execution.

Answer (score 1):

As you are writing to 2 different files (one file, one database), then the OS is perfectly within it's remit to perform the writes in whatever order is 'best' for the storage medium.

In the old days of spinning storage, the 2 requests would be in the write queue, and if the r/w heads were currently nearer the to the tracks for the database, than the file, then the OS (or maybe the HDD controller) would write the database data first, followed by the file data.

This assumes that both your file and your database server are running on the same physical machine.   If you are writing to a shared folder, and/or the DB server is also on a different machine, then who knows what order they will finish in.

Comment: Would tasks be completed in different order, though? Once the first task is awaited, and finished, the continuation (the rest of the method) executes, **then** the second task fires.

Comment: From the code point of view they would be executed in order, but from the OS point of view, the data storage may not be.

Comment: @Neil the using block around the file writing encompasses flush and close. I'm observing the file through the file system API, not by looking at bytes on disk. So while your answer is correct, It doesn't explain what I'm seeing.